# python: How to write variable-contents to a file?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, request, fwrite

How do I pass the variable-contents to the `f.write()` function, so that the variable-contents would be written to file?

> i.e. move variable jsonData to function f.write()

```
 def get(self):
        url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        jsonData = json.loads(data)  

        # #TODO: send jsonData variable to log file.
        f = open('test_logs.txt', 'a+')
        f.write('jsonData') 
        f.close()

        return jsonData
```

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.write(str(jsonData))
```

Though you should be writing to a json file probably

Comment: TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
127.0.0.1 ] "GET /RBT%20Test/rbt HTTP/1.1" 500

Comment: I made an edit. The `jsonData` needs to be made a string before you try to write it

Comment: Ok, when I just send the `data` variable instead of `jsonData` to f.write() it displays it correctly.

Comment: Yea that would be simpler. `data` is a string so no need to convert to json object to convert back to string.